# Updating webpack.dev.config from Webpack 1 to 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-4

For the open source site, [ReForum](https://github.com/shoumma/ReForum), I'm trying to update the site to the latest components (ie: webpack 4, react 16, etc). I started with babel and it upgraded smoothly. Then moved to webpack. I spent more than 10 hours trying various configs until I finally got it to compile using the following:

```
/**
 * module dependencies for webpack dev configuration
 * Proper webpack dev setup:
 * https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-develop-react-js-apps-fast-using-webpack-4-3d772db957e4

 */
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

// define paths
const nodeModulesPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules');
const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../public', 'build');
const mainAppPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../frontend', 'App', 'index.js');
const sharedStylesPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../frontend', 'SharedStyles');
const componentsPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../frontend', 'Components');
const containersPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../frontend', 'Containers');
const viewsPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../frontend', 'Views');

/**
 * webpack development configuration
 */
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  target: 'web',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',

  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    mainAppPath,
  ],

  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: buildPath,
    publicPath: '/build/',
  },

  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
      // both options are optional
      filename: '[name].css',
      chunkFilename: '[id].css',
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: [ 'babel-loader' ],
        exclude: [nodeModulesPath],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          // 'postcss-loader',
          { loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              plugins() {
                return  [autoprefixer('last 5 version')];
              },
              // plugins: () => [require('autoprefixer')({
              //   'browsers': ['> 1%', 'last 5 versions'],
              // })],
            },
          },
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      { test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, use: ['url-loader?limit=8192'] },
      { test: /\.svg$/, use: ['url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'] },
    ],
  },

  resolve : {
    // automatically resolve file extensions (ie import File from '../path/file')
    extensions: ['.js', '.css'],
    // alias to call specified folders
    alias: {
      SharedStyles: sharedStylesPath,
      Components: componentsPath,
      Containers: containersPath,
      Views: viewsPath,
    },
  },
};
```

[Original Webpack 1 dev config](https://github.com/shoumma/ReForum/blob/master/config/webpack.dev.config.js)

However, the React elements classname disappear, preventing the styles from being applied. It should be like:

[image: expected]

But instead is:

[image: bad]

Also, the head now have multiple `<style>`s .

[image: Multiple Unknown styles]

**Please help me get classnames to reappear and fix the multiple head style elements.**

---

FYI, the only way I was able to get postcss-loader to run is by turning it into an object. It would fail with errors like "Error: No PostCSS Config found in ... "

---

Update 1:

Tried @noppa and @Alex Ilyaev suggestions the following but it didn't work.

```
     {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          // 'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              loaders: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
              localIndentName:'[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
            },

          },
          // 'postcss-loader',
          { loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: 'inline',
              options: {
                ident: 'postcss',
                plugins: (loader) => [
                   require('autoprefixer')(),
                ],
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
```

Comment: It could be useful to also add the old webpack config. Someone might notice something missing or changed in the new one. Perhaps one of the source files too, to show how the class names are supposed to be linked to elements.

Comment: @noppa The original config file is shared in the ReForum github. The link is https://github.com/shoumma/ReForum/blob/master/config/webpack.dev.config.js .

Comment: A quick looks shows that you had options for `css-loader` that are now omitted. Try `{ loader: 'css-loader', options: { loaders: true, importLoaders: 1, localIndentName: ... }`

Comment: Try `plugins: [autoprefixer('last 5 version')]` under `postcss-loader > options`. I'm not sure the function variant is supported here. And @noppa 's comment as well.

Comment: @noppa Tried your suggestion but it didn't work. Updated question with my changes.

Comment: @AlexIlyaev Tried your suggestion but it didn't work. Updated question with my changes.

Comment: @noppa Your suggestion worked. I missed adding `modules` option. Thanks! Still have multiple `style` sheets though.

Comment: The postcss-loader settings are wrong, see: https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader

Comment: @SILENT Since this was more of a debugging session than an actual Q&A, IMO you could answer this question yourself telling what worked for your problem. Others might find it useful later and the question gets cleaned from open questions.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Webpack 4, start with no config file - that's right - no config file. WP4 includes sane defaults so most of your non webpack related issues will surface right there.

Regarding the multiple styles block, you need to switch to [mini-css-extract-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin) (doesn't support HMR) or [extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/faceyspacey/extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin) (supports HMR).

Also, note that during dev mode, you'll see multiple style blocks (for HMR). But production build should not have multiple style blocks.